# ad.loadclass crash on android 9

Tags: android, crash, admob

I am facing this crash on android 9 devices but can't find any solution to this. Can anybody help me fix this crash?
here is the crash report.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-86]
Unity version     : 2017.1.1f1
Device model      : samsung SM-G965U
Device fingerprint: samsung/star2qltesq/star2qltesq:9/PPR1.180610.011/G965USQU3CSAB:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at jq.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
  at jp.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
  at jr.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):15)
  at iu.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):20)
  at iu.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):8)
Caused by: java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

include this library "uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" "  in your android manifest file inside the library tag even if you are not using the google map services directly in your games. It will hopefully resolve the crash as it has fixed my crash.